# participant_fee_level Returns Inconsistent Data - Strings, Arrays, and Not Always the Same Information

Tags: participants, civimobile

For context, I'm trying to modify the [old CiviMobile extension](https://github.com/webaccess/com.webaccessglobal.module.civimobile) to utilize the Participant Check-in feature which generally works great!)  I'm not an experienced developer, just an interested employee of a theater company. That said, I was able to modify the code to do what we wanted pretty easily, except for this one point:

**participant_fee_level** seems to, at random, return different information. Sometimes it's a string. Sometimes it's an array. Either is fine. I can convert arrays to strings and parse those. However, it also seems to, at random, omit the "Participant Count -#" information that comes at the end, which is causing problems...

[image: Logged results of the participant_fee_level pull]

All of the Participant records are for events with the exact same price set.  Nothing about that price set or the events has been changed between registrations.

I much prefer pulling this kind of data using Line Items, but the extension is built using the APIv3, and I don't think that kind of Participant to Line Item join is possible?  (I tried to figure out if I could just update the whole extension to APIv4, but I think it's beyond my current knowledge level.)

I could also write a more complicated string parsing system to pull out individual price set options, but that's going to inherently be pretty sloppy, and I really *only* need the Participant Count.

Is there a better way to get the Participant Count information I want? Barring that, are there any ideas for how I can get a consistent result out of the participant_fee_level field?

Any ideas welcome! Thank you!